# Comment highlight group does not work without reloading .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, comments

The following line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
hi Comment ctermfg=gray
```

does not take effect unless I start Vim and then use `:source` to reload `.vimrc`. As far as I can tell, all of the other `hi` commands work without reloading `.vimrc`. What could be causing this?

This is my full `.vimrc`:

```
filetype indent plugin on                                                       
syntax on                                                                       

set number                                                                      
set relativenumber                                                              

set colorcolumn=80                                                              

set showcmd                                                                     

set expandtab                                                                   
set shiftwidth=4                                                                
set smarttab                                                                    

set list                                                                        
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~                                                    

hi ColorColumn ctermbg=0                                                        
hi LineNr ctermfg=gray                                                          
hi CursorLineNr ctermfg=gray                                                    
hi Comment ctermfg=gray                                                         
hi Function ctermfg=darkgreen                                                   

hi pythonStatement ctermfg=lightblue                                            
hi pythonConditional ctermfg=lightblue                                          
hi pythonRepeat ctermfg=lightblue                                               
hi pythonException ctermfg=lightblue                                            
hi pythonDecoratorName ctermfg=lightblue                                        
let python_no_number_highlight = 1
```

**Edit:** The output of `:verbose hi Comment` is:

```
Comment        xxx term=bold ctermfg=14 guifg=#80a0ff
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

So it appears that my setting is being overridden by the default syntax file. I will investigate how to solve this when I have time, but would appreciate any tips from more experienced users :)

Comment: What’s the output of `:verbose hi Comment?`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As Rich said, it would be great if you [edit] the results of the command `:verbose hi Comment` into your question

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this with the latest vim-nightly.

1. your `vimrc` loads first (where you have defined your highlighing)
2. then `syntax/synload.vim` does override it with:

```
" Set the default highlighting colors.  Use a color scheme if specified.
if exists("colors_name")
  exe "colors " . colors_name
else
  runtime! syntax/syncolor.vim
endif
```

where `syntax/syncolor.vim` is the one that defines default colors.

I have tried to setup:

```
let g:colors_name = "mycolorscheme"
let colors_name = "mycolorscheme"
hi Comment guibg=green
```

But it still thinks `colors_name` doesn't exist.

**Back to solution: Solution 1**

I would suggest to create your own colorscheme `.vim/colors/mycolorscheme.vim`

```
set background=light

hi clear
if exists('syntax_on')
    syntax reset
endif

let g:colors_name = 'mycolorscheme'

hi ColorColumn ctermbg=0                                                        
hi LineNr ctermfg=gray                                                          
hi CursorLineNr ctermfg=gray                                                    
hi Comment ctermfg=gray                                                         
hi Function ctermfg=darkgreen                                                   

hi pythonStatement ctermfg=lightblue                                            
hi pythonConditional ctermfg=lightblue                                          
hi pythonRepeat ctermfg=lightblue                                               
hi pythonException ctermfg=lightblue                                            
hi pythonDecoratorName ctermfg=lightblue
```

and in your `vimrc` use it:

```
filetype indent plugin on                                                       
syntax on                                                                       

set number                                                                      
set relativenumber                                                              

set colorcolumn=80                                                              

set showcmd                                                                     

set expandtab                                                                   
set shiftwidth=4                                                                
set smarttab                                                                    

set list                                                                        
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~ 

let python_no_number_highlight = 1

colorscheme mycolorscheme
```

**Solution 2**

Just add `colorscheme default` before your highlight definitions:

```
filetype indent plugin on                                                       
syntax on                                                                       

set number                                                                      
set relativenumber                                                              

set colorcolumn=80                                                              

set showcmd                                                                     

set expandtab                                                                   
set shiftwidth=4                                                                
set smarttab                                                                    

set list                                                                        
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~                                                    

colorscheme default

hi ColorColumn ctermbg=0                                                        
hi LineNr ctermfg=gray                                                          
hi CursorLineNr ctermfg=gray                                                    
hi Comment ctermfg=gray                                                         
hi Function ctermfg=darkgreen                                                   

hi pythonStatement ctermfg=lightblue                                            
hi pythonConditional ctermfg=lightblue                                          
hi pythonRepeat ctermfg=lightblue                                               
hi pythonException ctermfg=lightblue                                            
hi pythonDecoratorName ctermfg=lightblue                                        
let python_no_number_highlight = 1
```

PS, looks like `colorscheme` command does smth that sets up `colors_name` variable properly?

Comment: Solution 1 (creating my own colorscheme) worked for me, thanks!