# Set color of Comment only using .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

I am using some preset colorthemes, but it seems that the types `Identifier` and `Comment` always use the same color -- which makes my `.asm` files basically just one color. I tried to change the color of the comments with:

```
:highlight Comment ctermfg=Blue
```

and it works when I do it directly in *vim*, but if I put it in my `.vimrc` it does not work at all. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830125/change-font-color-for-comments-in-vim) but doesn't work for me.

Just in case, this is my `.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set expandtab

au InsertEnter * set ignorecase
au InsertLeave * set noignorecase

function! Html()
    r~/.vim/code/html.txt
endfunction

map <F6> :tabp<CR>
map <F8> :tabn<CR>
map <F7> :tabe<Space>

" Disable expandtab for Makefiles
let _curfile = expand("%:t")
if _curfile =~ "Makefile" || _curfile =~ "makefile" || _curfile =~ ".*\.mk"
set noexpandtab
else
set expandtab
endif

syntax on
highlight Comment ctermfg=Blue
```

With or without `syntax on` there's no effect.

I suspect something is changing the colors and overriding the effect of my `.vimrc` command, but I don't know what.

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose hi comment`

Comment: It seems that it's being overwriten:
Comment        xxx term=bold ctermfg=14 guifg=#80a0ff
            Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim

Comment: What is weird is that the color specified in that file for ctermfg is different than what is actually visible.

Comment: `syncolor.vim` is loaded when you do `syntax on`. And it just resets colors to vim defaults. Try change `highlight` to `highlight! ...`

Comment: My bad, this questions seemed familiar to me. I already answered similar one: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22840/comment-highlight-group-does-not-work-without-reloading-vimrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see you use any colorschemes so

```
:highlight Comment ctermfg=Blue
```

at the end of your vimrc should work.

Note though, if you use colorscheme, then your highlight would be overridden.

It is possible to do the following:

```
augroup colorscheme_change | au!
    au ColorScheme * :hi Comment ctermfg=blue
augroup end
```

Which defines autocommand group and an autocommand inside this group that upon colorscheme change runs your highlight comment command.

**UPDATE**

Check [Comment highlight group does not work without reloading .vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22840/comment-highlight-group-does-not-work-without-reloading-vimrc)

Try adding:

```
colorscheme default
highlight Comment ctermfg=Blue
```

to your vimrc.

Comment: Hi, I set the colorscheme via the terminal itself (xfce4-terminal), so I think maybe it does not affect vim directly? The command didn't work.

Comment: So you don't set a colorscheme in vim.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Wonderful! It worked perfectly. Thank you so much! My life just got 20% easier.